# Removing 2x4 strapping and still meeting Ontario building code

Tags: basement, ceiling, joists

I am finishing a basement ceiling in a new house. Currently there is a 2x4 used as strapping in the center of the area for the above floor joists. I want to remove it but dont want to create issues. I need ceiling height. I was going to put blocking in between joists to compensate. I have the house plans and the building code states that strapping is not required if furring strips or panel type ceiling fi Ian is attached directly to joists. Code also requires resilient channels for noise now. Will the channels meet this requirement and or will blocking be acceptable.
[image: strapping]

[image: blueprint]

[image: obc]

Answer (score 1):

No, RC-1 channels are not replacements for strapping, bridging, etc., even though it will be installed across the face of the basement ceiling and the strapping, etc. is installed 6’-11” o.c. (Please note that the strapping MUST BE fastened to the sill or header at ends. This is so the joists won’t “parallelogram” over when fully loaded.)

Yes, SOLID blocking is an acceptable substitute for strapping, bridging, etc., (but very time consuming. )